# What protocols do message queues use to communicate with clients?

Tags: java, message-queue

I have worked with message queues but never wondered, what protocol do they use to communicate? Basicly all of them support blocking methods e.g

```
// sleeps the thread until any message is available
Object message = queueService.take()
```

but i never wondered how is this implemented client-server(MOM) wise.

From what i read `RMI` is pretty much dead ( and not sure if it supports blocking methods) so what do modern day MQ use to communicate?

Is there any book/tutorial/course for implementing own queue or just describe these stuff in detail?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: RMI is a Java-only, CORBA-like API.  I believe Rabbit uses AMQP, which has clients in Java/Kotlin, C#, JavaScript/Node, Python, etc.  Kafka has its own protocol: https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html

Answer (score 2):

Some use proprietary protocols, others use one of several standards like [AMQP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) or [MQTT.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQ_Telemetry_Transport) The upshot is that a given client can only connect to a given message broker by careful design; you shouldn't assume that clients can be mixed and matched freely.

The variety of protocols is due in part to historical reason, as various vendors worked independently to build competing message-oriented middleware products. But today, there are still good reasons to support different protocols. For example, MQTT is lightweight and well-adapted to embedded devices, while AMQP is better suited to enterprise applications.

Comment: interesting, however how do they implement blocking methods? On local computer thread is awakened via scheduler/hardware locks but how do they awaken the thread if the method `take()` for example blocks? Is there busy waiting or are there any specific techniques? I would like to implement my own queue as practice, unfortunately these topics are sooo hard to find and info about them is almost non existent.

Comment: @Johnyb Does section *2.6.8 Synchronous Get* of the [AMPQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) spec answer your question?

Comment: @BasilBourque interesting, so its basicly just synchronous method call that waits for server to respond ( with or without timeout )without setting the thread to waiting state? However i have seen these methods supporting interrupted exceptions, is that just some API wrapper that just executes this synchronous method in new thread for better usage?

Comment: @Johnyb it seems like you are interested in blocking at two distinct layers, threading and network. At the threading level, fundamentally consumer threads will block on a `wait()` call, and producer threads will perform network IO to receive a message and then `notify()` waiting threads that it has arrived. The network IO can be blocking, asynchronous, or non-blocking.

Comment: @erickson yes, but if on thread level: the client code has to call lets say `take()` method, in that method has to be some kind of code to find out if there are some elements to take, i suppose its the call to the server and if it returns null then the `take()` method calls `wait()` on thread level. But how will server call `notify()` on `wait()` that was called on client? Since whole thread is in waiting state and there isnt busy waiting ( or is it busy waiting ? ). Im getting more and more confused here :)

Comment: @Johnyb The server doesn't call `notify()`; a thread in the client that is reading from the socket will call it after receiving a complete message.

Comment: @erickson im still confused,, the `take()` method blocks until data is present in queue on server, so internally it uses two threas ?  the code that fetches data from server e.g `socket.take()` is blocking method, so the `take()` one htread running the logic, that sleeps seelps itself, and have another thread running that just use `socket.take()` and when the data arrives it wakes up the running logic thread? This is interesting topic but im getting lost :(

Comment: @Johnyb Yes, in a way, that is correct. The running logic thread isn't "sleeping," it is "waiting," which is a little different. Consequently, the socket-reading thread doesn't "wake" the logic thread, it ["notifies"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) it. That makes the logic thread return from its call to [`wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait())  and continue running, now that the message from the server has arrived.

Comment: @erickson thanks, is there any resource you would recommend to read ? book, course, blog or udemy course or something about implementation of such technologies? Seems like basic concurrency practice but its so hard to find resources for this ( i dont mean about conurrency but practical examples from MS and so on ).

Comment: @Johnyb Recommendations for off-site resources is off-topic for StackOverflow, but I will say that *Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz has a wealth of info about fundamentals and advance topics in Java concurrency.

Comment: @erickson finished that book last weak, i was thinking maybe of more practical examples such as this queue and so on.